MariaDB: Hostname verification failed on startup
Running MariaDB11.5.2 on Debian 12.
I configured TLS which works perfectly. To make it work from shell, I configured
[client-mariadb]
host = dbhost.domain.tld

Now, I can connect from shell without problems usingmariadb -p.
But during startup, there still seems to be a problem
Dez 11 11:13:46 dbhost mariadbd[204214]: Version: '11.5.2-MariaDB-deb12-log'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
Dez 11 11:13:46 dbhost systemd[1]: Started mariadb.service - MariaDB 11.5.2 database server.
Dez 11 11:13:46 dbhost /etc/mysql/debian-start[204231]: Upgrading MariaDB tables if necessary.
Dez 11 11:13:46 dbhost /etc/mysql/debian-start[204235]: Reading datadir from the MariaDB server failed. Got the following error when executing the 'mysql' command line client
Dez 11 11:13:46 dbhost /etc/mysql/debian-start[204235]: ERROR 2026 (HY000): TLS/SSL error: Hostname verification failed
Dez 11 11:13:46 dbhost /etc/mysql/debian-start[204235]: FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
Dez 11 11:13:46 dbhost debian-start[204248]: ERROR 2026 (HY000): TLS/SSL error: Hostname verification failed

My config
[mysqld]
ssl_ca = /etc/ssl/certs/ca.pem
ssl_cert = /etc/acme/dbhost.domain.tld-fullchain.pem
ssl_key = /etc/acme/dbhost.domain.tld-key.pem
#require-secure-transport = on

The last setting is disabled because it seems to break my application. SSL is required on per user base. But I dont understand why the hostname verification fails then during startup.
It seems to configured hostname is not being used here. How to achieve to enforce SSL but see no errors like this in the logs?
Additional info
head /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost                                                                           
127.0.1.1       dbhost.domain.tld         dbhost   

root@dbhost ~ $ hostname -s
dbhost                                                                                               
root@dbhost ~ $ hostname -d
domain.tld                                                                                          
root@dbhost ~ $ hostname -f
dbhost.domain.tld


How is hostname on the server configured? What is the contents of the /etc/hosts and what says hostname -s, hostname -d and hostname -f?

I've added the requested information

It is suggesting that your hostname is not contained within the SSL cert. I would assume you would have to add dbhost.domain.tld.bsz-bw.de (or whatever it is) to your hosts file.

What do you mean? I have my FQDN in my hosts file, see line two in the /etc/hosts

I would expect startup scripts to use either localhost or the socket, not an FQDN. And localhost is most probably not contained in your certificate.

@GeraldSchneider+ the filenames suggest this cert is obtained from LetsEncrypt; if so, or from any other generally-trusted CA, it CERTAINLY is not valid for 'localhost', because CABforum rules prohibit issuing certs for 'Internal' (nonregistrable) names or 'Reserved' addresses (although if LE specifically, that doesn't issue for any addresses even those CABforum permits)

Of course, it's not valid for localhost. The question is why it enforces SSL for user root. I checked that root has no require SSL rule and the global require-secure-transport is commented out.

I think the problem is with Debian-specific startup procedure, which executes some check-and-upgrade commands in addition to mandatory starting mysqld process. Normally, for efficiency reasons if you direct mysql client to connect to localhost by name, it will be automatically reverted to Unix domain socket, which should bypass TLS entirely (as it is not useful there); it looks like for some reason the command Debian runs specifically requests connection to be made over TCP.

Commented the above [client] settings and tried:
mariadb -p -h localhost Enter password:  ERROR 2026 (HY000): TLS/SSL error: Hostname verification failed 
